# `setup.py test` cannot find package in own repo

Tags: python, testing, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to run tests with my `setup.py` as usually with `python setup.py test` with appropriate `setup.py` configuration. It was ok until I added a package from my own repository.

I can easily install it with `pip install my_package`, having the `--extra-index-url` in `/etc/pip.conf` or credentials in `~/.pypirc.` I also entered the url in `dependency_links` in the setup.py file!

But when I run it now, I see it knows about the module, but it is unable to download it!

```
(testpy3) honza@mycomp:~/.../xxxx_module$ python setup.py test
running pytest
Searching for package_yyyy
Reading https://specimen:specimen@repo.xxxxx.net/repository/pypi-private/simple
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/package_yyyy/
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/package_yyyy-grpc/
Couldn't find index page for 'package_yyyy' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for package_yyyy
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('package_yyyy')
```

In fact I want to use this in docker, but does not work locally nor in docker. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Most probably you have a wheel uploaded to your repo, but no source dist package. `python setup.py` commands can't handle wheels, instead looking for source distributions. Building a source tar (`python setup.py sdist`) and uploading it to the repo should help.

Comment: I used a workaround by using pip in the dockerfile, because it just would not work with `setup.py`'s `easy_install`.

Comment: Then add more information: what is the exact command you are running in your dockerfile and what is the error stacktrace? Also, what dist files did you upload to your private repo?